# z-index and opacity with one image partially on top of another, how can I remove the transparency?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have two images on my site, one is simply an image ( in the HTML file), while the other is the background of a container (the main part of the page) (defined in the CSS file as "background-image:url(x)") added to the HTML file via a  tag.  The rest of the page has a background of #eeeeee (slightly darker white).

The z-indexes of the two are set so the  image is on top of the background image, exactly what I want... However, I can see through the  image to the background image.  This is because the  has opacity:0.4 as a style attribute.  So it makes sense that it shows through to the background, but is there any way to make the  be transparent through to my #eeeeee background?

Comment: Just pre-edit the image to have transparency?

Comment: post a screenshot. what has opacity 0.4 what do you want to make transparent? make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `opacity` attribute to the css for the image.